# Conditional mapping in azure data factory

Tags: mongodb, azure, mapping, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory

I have created a pipeline in azure data factory which copy data from a collection (named `source`) from an azure table storage to a cosmos db storage (with mongoDB API) containing collection named `destination`.

I have an issue on how to copy an attribute named `EndDate` which is a date object. 
Indeed, I have to map this attribute to `endDate` attribute in mongo which is an object containing `date` property. I think this is necessary to be interpreted as a date by mongoDB. [image: azure data factory mapping]

The exactly mapping is the following :
[image: advanced mapping]

The problem here is I have some `EndDate` with null values. And `endDate['date']` can't receive null values because mongo throws an error (in fact mongo uses the function `ISODate(date)` to convert a string to a date and `ISODate(null)` can't work).

So my idea is to :

- map `EndDate` to `endDate['date']` when its value is not null
- map `EndDate` to `endDate` otherwise

Do you know how I can add this conditional mapping in azure data factory ?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 1):

As i know,you can't implement such conditional mapping in copy activity because it has some limitations or rules.Please refer to this [paragraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#alternative-column-mapping).

I suggest you getting idea of [Data Flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-data-flow) in ADF which could replace Copy Activity when you have some logical or complex needs in columns mapping.For your scenario,maybe [Conditional Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-conditional-split) is your option!

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer ! Unfortunately Azure Table Storage is not yet supported as dataflow source and that's frustrating because it seemed to be the best solution...
An other idea is to explore the dynamic content part in the mapping, do you know something about that ?

Comment: @Putxe How about using copy activity to transfer data from azure table storage into blob storage, then use data flow...?

Comment: @Putxe As i know,conditional mapping is not supported in copy activity schema mapping.Sorry...

Comment: @Putxe Sure! If any concern,please post here and i will follow that!